# Python, add elements to a dictionary maintaining same key

Tags: python, dictionary

What I need that I can't find a solution for is to add new elements to my dictionary even if there's already that key inside it. So if my dictionary is:

```
{'red': 1,
 'yellow': 2,
 'green': 3}
```

and I want to add

```
'red': 2'
```

I don't lose the 'red: 1' element, so I have:

```
{'red': 1,
 'yellow': 2,
 'green': 3,
 'red': 2'}
```

Comment: This is impossible, dictionaries **must** have **unique** keys. You can use a list of tuples as replacement. Or a dictionary of lists.

Comment: Keys in dict are unique, so you can't perform such operation. Instead you can store collection under some key e.q `{'red': [1, 2]}`